# Firebase Authentication: Where is the token stored in web?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was curious about how firebase auth token works.
Then I found this answer saying that token is stored in local storage.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62577638/7239472

However, when I checked local storage in Application tab of my Google Chrome inspector, there was nothing.

**So from where does the Firebase Auth SDK get the token value?**

I also checked that currentUser object contains token value but I'm not sure where that came from.

Comment: It is, indeed, in local storage.  That's the only place where web application code can write persistently that's not a cookie.

Comment: Thanks always for answering. I found this [Google Group Comment](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/wgSvjniKPQI/m/5BUymV7gAgAJ) so checked the indexedDB. Name firebaseLocalStorageDB exists and token values as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Token can be found in firebaseLocalStorageDB. Please refer to this path.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Firebase saves its connection-token on a storage called "indexedDB".

You can see it by doing: inspect->application->indexedDB then you will see a firebase "key-value table" called "firebaseLocalStorage".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm interested whether it was stored before in `localStorage` and now it was changed to `IndexedDB`? And does it somehow prevent reseting the token when user decides to delete cookies/history? Will deleting cookies affect the FCM token or not? I can't really find an answer to it.